# Apply Python formatting rules to files not ending in .py

Tags: python, formatting

I need to edit a few `.pyt` files, which are python code but specific to ESRI ArcGIS software.

Is there a variable that lists the file ending that python formatting is applied to that I could add `.pyt` to in order to have those files formatted?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want `python-mode` (or whatever) to turn on when you edit one of those files?  If so, you can adjust [`auto-mode-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Associating-modes-with-files.html).

Comment: got it, currently the python-mode is applied as: `("\\.py[iw]?\\'" . python-mode)` there's probably a way to change that regex but `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pyt\\'" . python-mode))` in my init.el did the trick.

Comment: `("\\.py[iwt]?\\'" . python-mode)` should do it then.

Comment: thanks @NickD, The way I'm currently doing it with `add-to-list`, I just update the variable each time emacs each time it's opened. Any thoughts about how to edit the variable in a way that it will persist across sessions? Like how is the rest of the list built and can I edit that? Maybe it's better to keep all of this custom stuff inside init.el.

Comment: It *is* better to keep it inside `init.el`: isn't that where you put the `add-to-list`? What I meant was to find the place in your `init.el` where `python-mode` is set for `.pyi` and `.pyw` files and add the `t` there. But if somebody else is doing that setting, then it's not worth worrying about it: the `add-to-list` method is fine.

Comment: ok yeah I believe the list is set by built in emacs defaults as it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view `auto-mode-alist` using:

```
M-x describe-variable RET auto-mode-alist
```

Then edit the list by adding to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pyt\\'" . python-mode))
```

Per the docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Associating-modes-with-files.html)